# Firebase with Google Identity Platform fails for Microsoft as IdP

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit, microsoft-oauth

In our Firebase project, we've enabled Microsoft as an IdP. After configuring the app in Azure and creating a Microsoft Business account, we can successfully login (using the popup method):

```
const provider = OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
```

However, Firebase then returns the following error: `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential`, although there is no existing account with that email address.

Interestingly, this seems to happen only in projects for which we have upgraded to use Google Identity Platform.